# Failing to get POST values from HTML form in PHP

Tags: php, html, post, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am struggling to get values from an HTML form into PHP variables using POST. It used to work but now no matter what I do it isn't working. Here is the php file:

```
<?php
    include "DBConn.php";

    session_start();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Register.css" type = "text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">       
            <form action="register.php" method = "post">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="txtName" value = <?php if(isset($_POST['txtName'])) echo $_POST['txtName'];?>>

                <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
                <input type="text" id="surname" name="txtSurname" value = <?php if(isset($_POST['txtSurname'])) echo $_POST['txtSurname'];?>>

                <label for="address">Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="address" name="txtAddress" value = <?php if(isset($_POST['txtAddress'])) echo $_POST['txtAddress'];?>>

                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="txtEmail" value = <?php if(isset($_POST['txtEmail'])) echo $_POST['txtEmail'];?>>

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="txtPassword" value = <?php if(isset($_POST['txtPassword'])) echo $_POST['txtPassword'];?>>

                <label for="password2">Re-enter Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password2" name="txtPassword2" value = <?php if(isset($_POST['txtPassword2'])) echo $_POST['txtPassword2'];?>>

                <div id="lower">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" name = "btnRegister">
                </div><!--/ lower-->
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    //Runs if btnRegister is clicked. Registers a user.
    if (isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) {
        //Assigns form data to variables
        $_SESSION["Name"] = $_POST['txtName'];
        $_SESSION["Surname"] = $_POST['txtSurname'];
        $_SESSION["Email"] = $_POST['txtEmail'];
        $_SESSION["Password"] = $_POST['txtPassword'];
        $_SESSION["Password2"] = $_POST['txtPassword2'];
        $_SESSION["Address"] = $_POST['txtAddress'];

        $sqlSelect = 
        "SELECT *
        FROM tbl_Customer
        WHERE Email = '{$_SESSION["Email"]}'";

        //Runs select query
        $result = $conn->query($sqlSelect);
        $md5pass = md5($_SESSION["Password"]);

        //Checks to see if user exists based on query
        if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
            //Checks to see if passwords match
            if ($_SESSION["Password"] == $_SESSION["Password2"]) {
                //Passwords match
                echo '<script>alert("Passwords match")</script>';
                
                //Insert statement to insert user into table
                $sqlInsert =    "INSERT INTO tbl_Customer (Name, Surname, Email, Password, Address)
                                 VALUES ('{$_SESSION["Name"]}','{$_SESSION["Surname"]}','{$_SESSION["Email"]}','$md5pass','{$_SESSION["Address"]}');";

                if ($conn->query($sqlInsert) === TRUE) {
                    echo '<script>alert("Registered successfully")</script>';
                } 
                else {
                    echo '<script>alert("Registration error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error)</script>';
                }
            }
            else {
                echo '<script>alert("Passwords do not match")</script>';
            }
        } 
        else {
            //User exists
            echo '<script>alert("User already exists, choose a different email.")</script>';
        }

        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
    }

 ?>
```

None of the alerts are working indicating that they echos are not working. Also, the second I click the register button I am taken to the login page which means the register button must be working. It doesn't give me any errors or messages.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Is this a single PHP file? Or two different ones?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] (emphasis on the **minimal**)

Comment: Code which you have given, shows that form post to register.php, but your post code is on same page..remove register.php from form action and then try..

Comment: If you solved the issue, either a) write an answer below, if you think it would help others (and attract upvotes for you), or b) delete the question, if you think it's too trivial or too specific to your situation to be of help to anyone. _Don't_ update the question to mark it "solved" or to include the answer. This is a Q&A site, not a forum - please follow the format. See https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer for more guidance. I've rolled back your inappropriate update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `action="register.php"` from `<form>` tag if your PHP code is on the same page as HTML code. The `action` attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted, since your PHP code is on the same page you should remove `action` and the form-data will be submitted on that same page.

Or

create a `register.php` and put PHP code there.